# how do I use a cookie to make a popup disappear?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have a popup that shows always when I reload the page and I need to make it disappear for 7 days after the user close it (in the right you can see my failed attempt to do it using cookies) If anyone knows how to do it please help :)

Comment: When you first show the popup, set a cookie containing the current time. When you reload the page, check if the cookie exists and if the current time is less than 7 days later.

Comment: What do you mean by "in the right"? Please post your code as text.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

When the popup loads on your screen, meaning every line of code used to generate the popup has been successfully run, you can add a cookie at the end of your code with and expiration time of 7 days.

like this:

```
document.cookie = "Key=;true" + expires=${Date.now().setDate(date.getDate() + 7)};
```

and then check every time you load the page, before you show the popup. If the cookie exists or not, show it based on that.